# Elasticsearch facet on multi-level nested document

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I'm trying to calculate facets in multi-level nested documents. And could not find any example in docs or google, but found this:

The nested element provides the path to the nested document (can be a multi level nested docs) that will be used. (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html#_all_nested_matching_root_documents)

But the following query does not work. What is the right way to query this facet?

http://pastie.org/8526599 - here is the mapping i'm trying to use

http://pastie.org/8526601 - and here is non-working query

Answer (score 5):

Solved. Correct syntax:

```
{
  "facets": {
    "tf": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "fares.directions.orig.city"
      },
      "nested": "fares.directions"
    }
  }
}
```

SO - in nested inside facet definition we need to select the deepest nested path, and fields must be referenced by full path